# Pdflatex does not read the TEX root line, how do I solve that?

Tags: pdftex, external-files

I have a `main.tex` file with several chapters in a sub folder included as: `\include{chapters/chapter01}`
Each of the chapters' tex file have the line `% !TEX root = ../main.tex` at the top of the file.
When I run pdflatex on the `main.tex` file all goes well:

```
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape main.tex
```

However, if I run the same command on `chapter01.tex` it stops with an error as it can not find a `\begin{document}`. The following commands fail to compile:

```
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape chapters/chapter01.tex
```

.

```
cd chapters
pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape chapter01.tex
```

Apparently pdflatex neglects the TEX root line.

Is there a way to let pdflatex recognize that there is a root file?

Comment: The `% !TEX root` line is for your editor, it's nothing to do with TeX itself

Comment: I didn't know that. I use Sublime Text with LatexTools. The built in compile command works fine, but it runs the full latexmk scripts which takes a while. I wanted to just run pdflatex once so I made a build system containing the above command. I'll see if I can somehow edit the LatexTools build system to only use pdflatex once.

Comment: How about just running pdflatex once on your main file with some terminal application?

Comment: @Holene, that is an option that works but for reasons of convenience I hoped the TEX root method would work.

Comment: @JosephWright If you would make that an answer I will accept it, as that is the most correct answer to the current question.

Comment: @BartArondson I use XeLatex and have a same question, did you solve the problem? thanks.

Comment: @PigCry No, but there's no solution as you can see in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `% !TEX root` line is for your editor, it's nothing to do with TeX itself. This particular form of 'magic comment' originates in the editor [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/), and while they are now understood by several other editors, TeX itself takes no notice of them. Thus to use this approach you have to using an editor/IDE, and one that understands the type of 'magic comment' you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Update: sorry, I read your question a bit too quick. At first I thought you were asking about the LaTeXing plug-in. However:

When using Sublime Text with LaTeXing you need a slightly different directive statement:

```
% -*- root: file_location -*-
```

When using LaTeXTools, the statement is supposed to be correct. Reading from the [LaTeXTools github documentation](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools)

> Multi-file documents are supported as follows. If the first line in
>   the current file consists of the text `%!TEX root = <master file name>`,
>   then tex & friends are invoked on the specified master file, instead
>   of the current one. Note: the only file that gets saved automatically
>   is the current one. Also, the master file name must have a .tex
>   extension, or it won't be recognized.
>
> There is also support for project files; this is to be documented.

I would recommend LaTeXing. It is free to try, and are in my opinion being maintained at a better rate compared to LaTeXTools

Comment: As this no longer is a proper answer, I'm open to deleting it if the OP or community feels it doesn't provide valuable information